# What would it mean for a parameter region to be E-stable but undeterminate?

Tags: new-keynesian-economics, dsge, dynamic-optimization, adaptive-learning

What would it mean for a parameter region for a dynamic system to be E-stable, but indeterminate?

E-stable: it's stable under learning... so this means, once in equilibrium, you stay there? Or does it mean you always get there under learning?

undeterminate: super sensitive to parameter changes, tipping points may occur easily, there are multiple equilibria, etc etc?

The two seem to rather contradict, however, this combination is put forward in Figure 3 of Bullard and Mitra's (2002) paper for their adaptive learning New Keynesian model for monetary policy rules.

The other combination, Determinate and E-unstable or stable, either way, seems easier to grasp.

reference
Bullard, J., & Mitra, K. (2002). Learning about monetary policy rules. Journal of Monetary Economics, 49(6), 1105–1129. https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3932(02)00144-7